# Android ListView items onClick with CursorAdapter only working after some clicks

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

This is the **ListFragment**:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        listList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_list);
        mListAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
        FloatingActionButton addFab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        addFab.setFocusable(false);
        addFab.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        mDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(getContext());
        mDBAdapter.open();

        id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
        latitudes = new ArrayList<Double>();
        longitudes = new ArrayList<Double>();
        descripciones = new ArrayList<String>();
        categorias = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        listList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

        empty = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tvEmpty);
        Cursor listas = mDBAdapter.getListaListas();
        if(listas==null || listas.getCount()<=0) empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        listList.setClickable(true);
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListViewClicked = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                cur = mDBAdapter.getListaListas();
                int id_lis;
                String name_lis;
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int k=0;k<i;k++){
                        cur.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                id_lis = cur.getInt(0);
                name_lis = cur.getString(1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MarkerListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("numLista", id_lis);
                Log.i("id_lista", ""+ id_lis);
                intent.putExtra("nameLista", name_lis);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        listList.setOnItemClickListener( myListViewClicked );
        listList.setLongClickable(true);
```

It has also a long click event that displays some options. At first, I put the Intent in there, but this is the common way to do it.

The adapter it's a normal CursorAdapter with only a textview in it.
These are the XML files:

**list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/click"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>


        <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#B6B6B6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the **fragment_list** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListFragment"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmpty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="Ninguna lista para mostrar"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_add" />
</FrameLayout>
```

So, how can I do to get the onItemClick working with a simple click? It always takes four or more clicks to open the new Activity.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Probably it works with a single click but takes some time till the other activity show up because you are doing database operations in the UI thread! In the meantime you think that it doesn't work and you click again and this gives you the impression that it needs more than one clicks. Why don't you put in the `onItemClick` method of your `OnItemClickListener` a `Toast` or a `Log.d` message to see if it prints with a simple click

Comment: I tried with that too, and the toast only appears sometimes, after multiple clicks :(

Comment: Toast should be on the first line above `cur = mDBAdapter.getListaListas();` You are doing database operations, better use `AsyncTask` for this. I will prepare an answer shortly.

Comment: `cur = mDBAdapter.getListaListas();...cursor iteration to position...` why? instead you should do it in normal way for `AdapterView` with `CursorAdapter` call `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)` and cast it to `Cursor` ...

Comment: I was trying for days and in that way it works if I use that code in the OnLongClick method. There's no problem in there, but thanks btw @Selvin

Comment: I did it leaving only the toast in the OnClick method, and it only works sometimes again after multiple clicks... @pleft

Comment: Just to make sure, you do know that you have to "click" on a list `item` (`onItemClick`) not just anywhere on the list. So you click on a list's item and it doesn't work with the first click and requires more clicks on exactly the same place of the screen (item) to work?

Comment: Exactly, and if I click in different parts of the item, it happens the same. Multiple clicks wherever I click @pleft

Answer (score 0):

Your `onItemClicked` method does database operations on the UI thread. This is something you should avoid and it causes bad user experience. Wrap your code inside an `AsyncTask` and `execute` it like the following:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Log.d("onItemClick", "clicked Item")
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    private int id_lis;
    private String name_lis;

     protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        cur = mDBAdapter.getListaListas();
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int k=0;k<i;k++){
                cur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        id_lis = cur.getInt(0);
        name_lis = cur.getString(1);
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MarkerListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("numLista", id_lis);
        Log.i("id_lista", ""+ id_lis);
        intent.putExtra("nameLista", name_lis);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
 }.execute();
}
```

Comment: I did this, but it's happening the same: the click only works sometimes, and that code doesn't open anything, sorry :/

Comment: Making iteration on another thread will not decrease it's time (prolly it will takes even more as creation of thread is costly) - it will only not block UI thread

Comment: Yes, and I try to wait but nothing happens, only if i click the item several times @Selvin

Comment: Even the `Log.d("onItemClick", "clicked Item")` message doesn't appear on the first click?

Comment: No, only after multiple clicks (sometimes at first, sometimes after 5 clicks) @pleft